# Which Windows 8 partitions are required?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

I upgraded my Acer laptop from `Windows 8 Home` to `Windows 8.1 Pro`. Now, this computer will only be used at work, so the `Factory Reset` feature is of no interest. Hence, there is some harddrive space to recover.

In `Disk Management` I can see the following partitions:

1. Recovery Partition 400 MB (contains recovery information dated before my upgrade)
2. EFI System Partition 300 MB
3. Recovery Partition 350 MB (contains recovery information from my upgrade)
4. Recovery Partition 17 GB
5. Primary Partition 220 GB

I want to delete all unnecessary partitions and merge them with my primary partition. I have a tool that can achieve this, but I don't know which partitions are needed by Windows. I'm sure I can delete the 17 GB partition, but what about the other recovery partitions?

Which partitions can I delete? (Also, does the order of the partitions matter?)

Comment: Why do you have three recovery partitions?  If you have backups you don't need any of the recovery partitions

Comment: Two were there when I bought the computer. The third appeared when I upgraded to 8.1.